# Right way to transform D3 into AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js

So I have been doing a lot of experimenting with D3 but have never attempted to turn it into an AngularJS directive, and I am not even sure of the proper way to change it over. I have an example that I believe I turned into an Angular D3 chart however I believe there are more efficient ways in loading the data , maybe in a $scope.data... Please use my jsfiddle to reference or correct.

https://jsfiddle.net/bcnmLrns/1/

```
var app = angular.module("chartApp", []); {

  var data = {
    "nodes": [{
      "name": "hblodget",
      "group": 1,
      "size": 1,
      "image": null
    }, {
      "name": "DowntownDonna69",
      "group": 1,
      "size": 20,
      "image": "http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/636139174672732160/L5cd008s_normal.jpg"
    }, {
      "name": "PupsherLive",
      "group": 1,
      "size": 19,
      "image": "http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/378800000210840839/93a8ba3852a8e20364957eb8b907b6b3_normal.jpeg"
    }],
    "links": [{
      "source": 1,
      "target": 0,
      "value": 1
    }, {
      "source": 2,
      "target": 0,
      "value": 1
    }]
  };


  var width = 960,
    height = 500;

  var color = d3.scale.category20();

  var force = d3.layout.force()
    .charge(-120)
    .linkDistance(30)
    .size([width, height]);

  var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

  d3.json(data, function(error, graph) {
    if (error) throw error;

    force
      .nodes(graph.nodes)
      .links(graph.links)
      .start();

    var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
      .data(graph.links)
      .enter().append("line")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .style("stroke-width", function(d) {
        return Math.sqrt(d.value);
      });

    var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
      .data(graph.nodes)
      .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("r", 5)
      .style("fill", function(d) {
        return color(d.group);
      })
      .call(force.drag);

    node.append("title")
      .text(function(d) {
        return d.name;
      });

    force.on("tick", function() {
      link.attr("x1", function(d) {
          return d.source.x;
        })
        .attr("y1", function(d) {
          return d.source.y;
        })
        .attr("x2", function(d) {
          return d.target.x;
        })
        .attr("y2", function(d) {
          return d.target.y;
        });

      node.attr("cx", function(d) {
          return d.x;
        })
        .attr("cy", function(d) {
          return d.y;
        });
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: are you open to using ng3d - http://nvd3.org at all?  It's a wrapper that sits on top of d3 and exposes some APIs to make it a **little** less verbose.

Comment: Also there are existing D3 directives you can use https://github.com/xibbit/ngD3 or https://github.com/zzmp/ngD3

Comment: Have you checked [this](https://gist.github.com/auser/6506865)? It is good to get the feel of integration both with angular directive.

Comment: So I am building a force-directed graph

Comment: Also another main reason is so I can do unit testing

Comment: I have yet to dive into this stuff, but you might want to check out angularize.d3: https://github.com/timruffles/d3.angularize I think he did a talk on it at the most recent angular conference: https://youtu.be/sUVXQKxt7Og

Answer (score 0):

You can use other directives and services people have made to make D3 easier to use in Angular (see comments on question), but I still like the easy setup of modularizing graphs and such inside a simple directive:

```
myApp.directive('graph', function() {
  var graphLink = function(scope, element) {
    var width = 960,
    height = 500;

   var color = d3.scale.category20();

   var force = d3.layout.force()
     .charge(-120)
     .linkDistance(30)
     .size([width, height]);

     var svg = d3.select(element[0]).append("svg") // attach d3 to directive element
       .attr("width", width)
       .attr("height", height);

     d3.json(data, function(error, graph) {
       if (error) throw error;

       force
         .nodes(graph.nodes)
         .links(graph.links)
         .start();

       var link = svg.selectAll(".link") // there might be a more angular way to do this...
         .data(graph.links)
         .enter().append("line")
         .attr("class", "link")
         .style("stroke-width", function(d) {
           return Math.sqrt(d.value);
         });

       var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
         .data(graph.nodes)
         .enter().append("circle")
         .attr("class", "node")
         .attr("r", 5)
         .style("fill", function(d) {
           return color(d.group);
         })
         .call(force.drag);

      node.append("title")
        .text(function(d) {
          return d.name;
        });

      force.on("tick", function() {
        link.attr("x1", function(d) {
          return d.source.x;
        })
          .attr("y1", function(d) {
            return d.source.y;
          })
          .attr("x2", function(d) {
            return d.target.x;
          })
          .attr("y2", function(d) {
            return d.target.y;
          });

        node.attr("cx", function(d) {
          return d.x;
        })
        .attr("cy", function(d) {
          return d.y;
        });
      });
    };

  return {
    link: graphLink, // pass in your link function here
    scope: {
      data: '=' // pass in your data as an attribute
                // this makes this reusable, and you can redraw if the data changes
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: do you mind putting this in a jsfidde with some data to show what you mean.

Comment: @user2402107- Here's an example I found by googling: http://jsfiddle.net/odiseo/ZnkN6/light/

Comment: this is a good example of angularjs and d3 however does not answer the force directed graph problem with nodes and links... its hard to use this example to show what you mean...

Comment: also after using your answer above it doesnt even run properly and has several errors, even after fixing them it doesnt do anything